# Problem to get data from ajax call to php

Tags: php, ajax

Did simple test pages for sending data via ajax call to php where I'm trying to check field (failing in here), from some reason don't get this working so where is my error ?

```
$.ajax({
     url:  "checkAJAX.php",
     data: {"test" : " Sending string from  ajaxToPHP file"}, 
     success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       $("#content").val(data);
     }
  });


<?php
if(isset($_GET["test"])){
    $checkField = $_GET["test"];
    echo $checkField;
}
else {
echo "<br>not working...";
}
?>
```

Comment: Add the `error: function(xhr, status, error){console.log(error)}` to check for possible errors. Anyway, what does `data` returns?

Comment: Thx Carl, problem is that there doesn't to be any error as success path is taken :) However in php file it doesn't echo anything so don't know what to do..